# Geojson to json

Tags: javascript, json, geojson, qgis

I need help trying to get a json file from the output of the QGIS2WEB plugin. There is only what appears to be a geojson output that has a .js extension and has this header:

```
var geojson_filename = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
....
]
```

Qgis itself only produces geojson files but I need a json format.

Some background: I need to get a json map to use in Power BI. I have the map in many formats; mapinfo tab, qgis shape, qgis geojson, html but for the life of me can't get a json format. Because of data sensitivity, I would like to avoid online converters.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `geojson_filename` looks like JSON. Link please.

Comment: GEOJSON is JSON, it just defines a specific set of rules the defines a data model. Is it possible you need the data from the QGIS2WEB plugin transformed into another output? If so, please define the output you would expect to see.

Comment: QGIS2WEB doesn't offer an output format selection, it only selects the folder.

Comment: This sounds like a question for a software support forum and not a programming question.

Comment: Both are objects in which you can manipulate.